# Docker Network Nginx Resolver

Tags: networking, nginx, docker

I am trying to get rid of deprecated Docker links in my configuration. What's left is getting rid of those `Bad Gateway` nginx reverse proxy errors when I recreated a container.

Note: I am using Docker networks in bridge mode. (`docker network create nettest`)

I am using the following configuration snippet inside nginx:

```
location / {
      resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
      set $backend "http://confluence:8090";
      proxy_pass $backend;
```

1. I started a container with hostname `confluence` on my Docker network with name `nettest`.
2. Then I started the nginx container on network `nettest`.
3. I can ping `confluence` from inside the nginx container
4. `confluence` is listed inside the nginx container's `/etc/hosts` file
5. nginx log says `send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.1:53`
6. I tried the docker network default dns resolver `127.0.0.11` from `/etc/resol.conf`
7. nginx log says `confluence could not be resolved (3: Host not found)`

Anybody knows how to configure nginx resolver with Docker Networks or an alternative on how to force Nginx to correctly resolve the Docker network hostname?

Comment: Does not look like this will be solved in any way without a network driver. The cause is Nginx by their need for an ip for a resolver and this can't be linked automatically to any Docker managed DNS resolver.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

First off, you should be using the Docker embedded DNS server at `127.0.0.11`.

Your problem could be caused by 1 of the following:

1. nginx is trying to use IPv6 (AAAA record) for the DNS queries.

   See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35516395/1529493 for the solution.

   Basically something like:

   ```
   http {
       resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
   }
   ```

   This is probably no longer a problem with Docker 1.11:

   > Fix to not forward docker domain IPv6 queries to external servers
   >   ([#21396](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/21396))
2. Take care that you don't accidentally override the `resolver` configuration directive. In my case I had in the `server` block `resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;` from [Mozilla's SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/), which was overriding the `resolver 127.0.0.11;` in the `http` block. That had me scratching my head for a long time...

Comment: Hardcoding the IP address of the Docker DNS resolver (`127.0.0.11`) shouldn't be an issue, as it won't change. Note that the Docker DNS resolver is only available with user defined networks (`docker network create ...`).

Reference: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22652

Comment: More official reference for the previous comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#/docker-embedded-dns-server

Comment: I had to add `ipv6=off` when running nginx in kubernetes

Comment: How do I check inside the container that Nginx Resolves it ?

Comment: @Fazy Why would it be necessary to perform such a check?

Comment: I'm getting errors like `6#6: send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.11:53` I tried both `resolver 127.0.0.11;` as well as `resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;` to no avail. Anyone else figured out?

Comment: @Tony Don't use a hardcoded DNS resolver address. And please make sure you're using a user-defined network. The default network works differently.

Comment: Actually, @MarcoRoy was right. The documentation guarantees that the address of the embedded DNS resolver in user-defined networks is always 127.0.0.11 - the documentation has moved to https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/

Comment: You should also add to your answer you need to setup a link between the nginx container and the backend service. On my docker compose, I didn't add `depends_on:  - rs-gateway` and it only started to work when I add it. You can also say the `127.0.0.11` IP comes from `/etc/resolv.conf` and may varies depending of the docker runner.

Comment: Hey that's me again after 1 year !!! Your configuration is not good for docker swarm : take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46664433/2294168 (needs to set `valid=10s` and use `set` to define a dynamic variable and bypass DNS cache)

Comment: when I add 'resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;' Nginx throws this exception: 'host not found in resolver "ipv6=off"'

Comment: Just using resolver 127.0.0.11 inside server block did the tricky for me. docker + docker-compose separate network from default.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe you should check your container's `/etc/resolv.conf`

It shows your container's correct DNS config and then use that DNS server IP for resolver.

`127.0.0.11` does not works in Rancher

Comment: Oh sorry, just for additional recommendation. Because my friend complained it did not work, maybe we'd read answers more carefully

Comment: @L.Guthardt, please, don't write such comments. They do not help people, while this answer does.
@exiaohao, it seems, Docker uses different DNS (not 127.0.0.11) when Weave address space is constrained by CIDR. Setting the resolver to nameservers IP noted in containers `/etc/resolv.conf` helped. Thanks.

Comment: Using the value in `/etc/resolv.conf` worked for AWS ECS Docker containers.

Answer (score 7):

I was running "node:12.18-alpine" with angular frontend and hit the same problem with proxy_pass.

Locally it was working with:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11;
```

As simple as that! Just execute:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver
```

In your container to get this ip address.

However, when deploying to kubernetes (AWS EKS) I got the very same error:

```
failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.11:53
```

**Solution:**

First solution was to find out the IP of the kube-dns service like below:

```
$ kubectl get service kube-dns -n kube-system
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns   ClusterIP   172.20.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   178d
```

Simple replacing IP for CLUSTER-IP worked like a charm.

Later, after some more doc digging, I find out that I could reference the service by name (which is little bit more elegant and resilient):

```
resolver kube-dns.kube-system valid=10s;
```

Comment: If nginx manages to resolve "kube-dns.kube-system" then I don't get why this needs to exist in the configuration.  However, this is the only thing that worked for me in k8s.  I don't think k8s uses docker anymore so the 127.0.0.11 trick doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Phil, when you deploy to kubernetes /etc/resolv.conf has its nameserver changed to kube-dns IP. That's why it can resolve "kube-dns.kube-system". "127.0.0.11" is what I use to run it locally. Regarding docker and k8s support, well, I'm still on 1.18 :-)

Comment: Yeah I see, but resolving a resolver feels a bit incestrious.  If nginx can already resolve the resolver name using OS DNS/resolv.conf, why does it still need to be told how to resolve other names such as those in proxy_pass.

Comment: I see your point now. True thing. Unfortunately, I cannot answer that, but just say that's what works for me too :-(

Answer (score 6):

My problem was **$request_uri** at the end. After adding it at the end of uri and changing the 127.0.0.1 to **127.0.0.11** solved my issue. I hope it will help people to not spend hours on this.

```
location /products {
            resolver 127.0.0.11;
            proxy_pass http://products:3000$request_uri;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

In several cases where I had this error, adding `resolver_timeout 1s;` to the Nginx config solved the issue. Most of the time I don't have a `resolver` entry.

Edit: what also worked for containers where I could explicitly define a nameserver: `resolver DNS-IP valid=1s;`

Answer (score 1):

We hit this with docker containers on windows trying to lookup `host.docker.internal` using the docker internal resolver at `127.0.0.11`. All queries would resolve correctly except `host.docker.internal`. Fix was to add the `ipv6=off` flag to the resolver line in `nginx.conf`.

Comment: Did you mean `127.0.0.11`, not `172.0.0.11`?

Comment: I did. Corrected. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the following way:

```
docker run --rm -d --network host --name "my_domain" nginx
```

https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the accepted answer work just fine for connecting containers under the same Docker network but it'll not work for `host.docker.internal` or any domain using `--add-host` or `extra_hosts` in compose because Docker's default DNS 127.0.0.11 does not include  `extra_hosts` and `--add-host` entries which are stored to `/etc/hosts` file. 2 simple workarounds are:

1. Change host.docker.internal to 172.17.0.1 which it's not sure whether Docker will always use the same IP.
2. Install dnsmasq and run dnsmasq inside the container. Set nginx resolver to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score -3):

You need a local dns server like `dnsmasq` to resolve using 127.0.0.1. Try installing it using `apk add --update dnsmasq` and set it up if you're using an alpine (`nginx:alpine`) variant.