# Trouble scaling docker container

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose

I have a dockerized flask app which has the following structure

```
code_docker
├── docker-compose.yml
├── micr
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── templates
│       └── index.html
├── nginx
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── nginx.conf
└── README.md
```

I am using `nginx` as a load balancer, The code inside `docker-compose.yml` and `nginx.conf` are mentioned below

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx
    restart: always
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8540:8540"
    depends_on:
      - micr

  micr:
    build: ./micr
    restart: always 
    deploy: 
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50' # 50% of available processing time (CPU)
          memory: 50M  # 50M of memory
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 20M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure   
    expose:
      - "8530"
    command: gunicorn -w 1 -b :8530 app:app
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user nginx;

worker_processes 4;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    keepalive_timeout 15;

    server {
        listen 8540;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8530;
            #proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forward-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

I can issue the below command to scale the container without any problem as can be seen from the [message](https://i.postimg.cc/hvYmXkNV/msg.png)

```
docker-compose up --scale micr=4
```

But when I try to access them I get this error

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to connect? 0.0.0.0 looks wrong.

Comment: @tripleee `http://localhost:8530/` or `http://0.0.0.0:8530/`

Comment: `localhost` is 127.0.0.1, not 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to create a network for Nginx and proxied containers. For details see [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

```
services:
  nginx:
    networks:
      - proxy
    ...

  micr:
    networks:
      - proxy
    ...

networks:
  proxy:
```

- You need to use service names as container host addresses to archive communication between containers.
  So set `proxy_pass` to `http://micr:8530`
- You should set docker embedded dns to nginx resolver to achieve ability to recreate containers without having to restart nginx container. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744650/docker-network-nginx-resolver) for details

Comment: You are the saviour

Comment: (Docker Compose will automatically create a network for you and you don't need to make one explicitly; but the advice to use the container name as a hostname is right on.)