# 504 response from ngingx reverse proxy with nodejs + docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

**UPDATE**

I have found out that it works if I restart nginx on the container with `docker exec -it backend_gateway_1 nginx -s reload`. I have found some information from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277079/nginx-requires-reload-after-reboot). It seems that connecting to 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost would work, however I am using docker networks so I'm not sure what my situation would be.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I am trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy with docker. I cannot quite work out what's wrong as sometimes it works when but then if I use `docker-compose down && docker-compose up` to restart it all, i will then usually get this 504 error

I have a feeling this is to do with the nginx or docker configuration. I am able to make a request to / fine but any request to /user is causing the intermittent issue.

When I am not receiving a 504, the node app is working well and creates/returns a user. I am also able to connect to the database fine with mongo-express so that should help narrow something down.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yml
version: '3.5'
services:
  gateway:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
    networks:
      - poker_network
  poker_mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: poker_mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db-data:/data/db
    expose: 
      - "27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: test
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
    networks:
      - poker_network
    depends_on:
      - gateway
  poker_user:
    container_name: poker_user
    build: ./user/
    image: poker/user:latest
    volumes:
      - ./user/:/usr/src/app
      #- /usr/src/app/node_modules
    expose:
      - "8080"
    depends_on:
      - gateway
      - poker_mongo
    networks:
      - poker_network
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: poker_mongo:27017
  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8085:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: test
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: 123
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: poker_mongo
    depends_on:
     - gateway
     - poker_mongo
    networks:
      - poker_network

networks:
  poker_network:
volumes: 
  db-data:
```

**nginx.conf**

```conf
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        location /user {
            rewrite /user/(.*) /$1  break;
            proxy_pass http://poker_user:8080/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
        location / {
            return 200 'hello';
        }

    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your node app doesn’t sporadically fails to handle request and doesn’t return any response? You could try removing all logic from `/user` handler and return `200` status code and see if you can reproduce the error. If you could add handler code that would also help.

Comment: yes sorry I meant to mention I have already tried this and It gets 504. It doesn't start out working, it either does work or doesn't and I get no output in the logs of the node app failing.  I will try create a simple example to add

Comment: @IgorNikolaev I've added some updates with what I've found out

Comment: You could try to change the order of dependencies - `gateway` should depend on `poker_user`

Comment: @IgorNikolaev Thank you, this worked. I seemed to have the idea about `depends_on` backwards when it came to NGINX. Could you please add this as an answer?

Comment: great that it helped. One more question though - would it work in previous set up if you wait a bit longer before testing?

Comment: @IgorNikolaev no, I tried waiting as well and it was only after the reload it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found several similar related questions and will try to compile two possible solutions out of those:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/240476/how-to-force-nginx-to-resolve-dns-of-a-dynamic-hostname-everytime-when-doing-p
- [Docker Network Nginx Resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744650/docker-network-nginx-resolver)

**First solution**

First solution is to reverse dependency between services: instead of `poker_user` depend on `gateway` you can may `gateway` depend on user. This way when `gateway` starts if will be able to resolve `poker_user` hostname.

The Dockerfile would look this way in this case:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  gateway:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on: poker_user
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
    networks:
      - poker_network
  poker_mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: poker_mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db-data:/data/db
    expose: 
      - "27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: test
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
    networks:
      - poker_network
  poker_user:
    container_name: poker_user
    build: ./user/
    image: poker/user:latest
    volumes:
      - ./user/:/usr/src/app
      #- /usr/src/app/node_modules
    expose:
      - "8080"
    depends_on:
      - poker_mongo
    networks:
      - poker_network
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: poker_mongo:27017
  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8085:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: test
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: 123
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: poker_mongo
    depends_on:
     - gateway
    networks:
      - poker_network

networks:
  poker_network:
volumes: 
  db-data:
```

I also removed some other dependencies as I think they are redundant.

**Second solution**

This solution is based on changing `nginx` configuration. It looks like `nginx` tries to resolve hostname specified in `proxy_pass` upfront and since it's not available yet when `nginx` starts it will keep responding with `504` because it doesn't try to resolve it again.

There seems to be a workaround with using variables inside `proxy_pass` directive which are treated differently and force `nginx` to perform DNS resolution again. This requires resolver to be configured in `nginx` and [luckily there's one](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/) built into Docker when using user-defined networks.

Here's an example `nginx` configuration (though I haven't tested it myself):

```
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        location /user {
            # Docker DNS server in user-defined networks
            # https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/
            resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

            rewrite /user/(.*) /$1  break;

            # Using a variable will force nginx to re-resolve DNS name
            # https://serverfault.com/a/593003
            set $backend "http://poker_user:8080/";
            proxy_pass $backend;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
        location / {
            return 200 'hello';
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this help!