# Django and nginx connected via a bridge network.How to parse domain and pass it to the proxy_pass?

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I am working on a multi tenant app. I have nginx as a rev-proxy
When a tenant registers I create a docker image and name it based on his subdomain
Lets call tenant1 t1 and tenant2 t2.

So t1.localhost.web to should be routed to t1.web:8000 where t1 is extracted from url in nginx  by regex and concatenated to ".web:8000" and it becomes t1.web:8000 and set to proxy_pass  in nginx.conf

These dockers containers also have a bridged network and they can be reached by their names. So if you bash into one of these containers you can ping or curl each other by their names it worksm so they are reachable by name

curl http://t1.web:8000  actually works given if you are "bash"ed into nginx container

this is my config file

```
events {
    worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}
http {

  

  # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
  server {
    server_name             ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.app\.dev;
    listen                  80;
    

   
    location / {
      set $domainweb        "http://$subdomain.web:8000";
      proxy_pass            $domainweb;
      proxy_set_header      Host $host;
      proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      
    }
    

  }
}
```

to debug I tried to exclude the subdomain variable and tried

```
location / {
      set $domainweb "http://t1.web:8000";
      
      proxy_pass            $domainweb;
      proxy_set_header      Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      
    }
```

that also did not work but when I do

```
 location / {
          
          
          proxy_pass            http://t1.web:8000;
          proxy_set_header      Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          
        }
```

It worked, So there is an issue with proxy_pass and regular expressions that I cant wrap my head around.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

You have to force to look at internal dns server

[Docker Network Nginx Resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744650/docker-network-nginx-resolver)

basically adding

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
```

under in http bracket solved my issue